# Delete file attachments for appointments using Exchange Web Services (EWS) does not work

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am trying to delete the old attachments added to an appointment using EWS API. However, EWS send the new updated email appointment with the "old attachments", even though i can see in debugging mode that the EWS Attachment collection his being deleted. This is my code.

```
Appointment existingMeeting = Appointment.Bind(service, meeting.MeetingExchangeID, new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject,
            AppointmentSchema.Location,
            AppointmentSchema.RequiredAttendees,
            AppointmentSchema.Resources));

existingMeeting.Attachments.Clear();
existingMeeting.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is a bug with EWS.

Maybe try and update the meeting firstly, without the `ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite` parameter, and then update with the parameter added.

Basically, add this line above your update code:

```
existingMeeting.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```

Comment: @D.B did this work for you? If so, please mark as answer.